# query works on sql server management studio 2008 but not in delphi

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi

I'm developing a program to update some fields in a table in delphi 7 using sql server. 
the program goes like this:

```
sql := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET '
      +' id_schedule = '+quotedstr(label_id_schedule.Caption)
      +',start_date = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',DateTime_start.Date))
      +',finish_date = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',DateTime_finish.Date))
      +',contract_location = '+quotedstr(uppercase(Edit_location.Text))
      +',sign_date = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',DateTime_sign.Date))
      +' WHERE id = '+quotedstr(label_id.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sql;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

when I run the program, it gives me an error: 'Incorrect syntax near '=''. but when I use showmessage to view the query and run it in sql server management 2008, it works fine.

then I try to split the query into parts like this:

```
SQL := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET '
      +' id_schedule = '+QUOTEDSTR(label_id_schedule.CAPTION)
      +' WHERE id = '+quotedstr(label_id.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sql;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

SQL := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET '
      +' start_date = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',DateTime_start.Date))
      +' WHERE id = '+quotedstr(label_id.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sql;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

SQL := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET '
      +' finish_date = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',DateTime_finish.Date))
      +' WHERE id = '+quotedstr(label_id.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sql;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

SQL := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET '
      +' contract_location = '+quotedstr(uppercase(edit_location.Text))
      +' WHERE id = '+quotedstr(label_id.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sql;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

SQL := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET '
      +' sign_date = '+quotedstr(formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',DateTime_sign.Date))
      +' WHERE id = '+quotedstr(label_id.Caption);
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sql;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

then I found out that it only triggers the error when updating a date type field. I have developed other programs to update different tables using similar query and it works fine.. I tried closing the project and reopening it but it still gives me that error message. please tell me what I should do..

Comment: Definitely use parameters. But be aware that 'mm/dd/yyyy' is not a reliable format (it can switch the month and day). Use 'yyyymmdd' in the future.

Comment: oh? can I edit the date format in sql server? I used mm/dd/yyyy because I thought that was the format used in sql server for datetime?

Comment: Nope. Not a valid assumption.

Comment: 'yyyymmdd' is iso so it should be safe to use.

Answer (score 14):

To avoid convertions and create database independed save querys you should use parameters, which also could speed up operations if used more than once.

```
  Adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE tb_dt_contract SET finish_date=:df where WHERE id =:id';
  // in some cases it may be necessary to add  the three comented lines
  //Adoquery1.Parameters.ParseSQL(Adoquery1.SQL.Text,true);
  //Adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('df').DataType := ftDateTime;
  //Adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('id').DataType := ftInteger;
  Adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('df').Value :=DateTime_finish.Date;
  Adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value :=StrToInt(label_id.Caption);
  Adoquery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Bummi, maybe add the fact that Adoquery.ParamCheck must be set to True before setting the SQL text

Comment: @whosrdaddy thanks, indeed it will make it more comfortable.
Adoquery.ParamCheck default is true, you can use it with Adoquery.ParamCheck:=false and doing it on your own:
Adoquery1.Parameters.ParseSQL(Adoquery1.SQL.Text,true);
Adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('df').DataType := ftDateTime;
......

Comment: Bummi - I think ID should be (var)char, no need for StrToInt

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out! (more like, my colleague did)

apparently after replacing the FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy' with datetostr and setting the shortdateformat to 'mm/dd/yyyy', the query works fine. I wonder why that is, though? I thought those commands do the same thing?

Comment: Don't do it this way. Do it they way Bummi said.

Comment: The difference may be that you did not set the DateDelimiter, only ShortdateFormat

Comment: This is because DateToStr without formatsettings uses your localized machine settings and your database just might or might not like the format. Using FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',... gets rid of ambiguities: consider 01/02/03, for some people on the world this is january 2nd 2003 but for others 1st of februari 2003 and even some will say 2001, februari 3rd. YYYYMMDD is universal. 20030201 is always 1st of februari 2003.